# Pygame examples don't show anything in my Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I installed pygame by running the following command:

```
pip install pygame==1.9.2
```

I also downloaded pygame github repo (https://github.com/pygame/pygame) and tried to run some examples under examples folder:

```
python aliens.py
```

This doesn't show any window or screen but I can hear some sound effects. What went wrong?

Comment: Pygame 1.9.2 is an old version. Try to install version 1.9.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out Pygame doesn't work with Python 3.5. I had to upgrade the version to 3.7